# How to update a inline style generated by browser in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Problem is like that
Box have a resize css attribute that allow user to change size of it. It updating inline style `height`.
As well there is a button that changing a size of same box.
Both functionalities are working fine until user will not start using both of them together.
Problem arrive when user start resizing box than browser are adding inline style to div ie:`style="height:40px"` this inline style is stronger than any style that is coming from css file so button in fact stop working and box can't be resized any more by using button, if im add `!important` rule to css than browser resizing functionality do not work any more because important override inline rule.
I make an attempt to reset style by using `reset` but it do not work if user start using resize.
So

How to reset/update style that is generated by browser when user using resize functionality?

```
<div class="terminal_in_body terminal_size-@terminalSize" style="@reset">

<button class="terminal_btn @(terminalSize == 0?"button_hidden":"button_visiable")" @onclick="Collaps" title="Extend/Hide terminal" >@(terminalSize == 0?"^":"_")</button>

@code {
  string reset = "";
  int terminalSize = 1; // 0 - collaps, 1 - 10% of screen, 2 - 20% of screen and so one
  public void Collaps()
  {
    reset = "xx";
    terminalSize++;
    if(terminalSize > 4)
      terminalSize = 0;
    InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
  }
}
```

Element cut from browser after use of resize functionality rule `height` is overriding `terminl_size-1` rule and i cant find a way to reset it.

```html
<div class="terminal_in_body terminal_size-1" style="height: 342px;" ></div>
```

```css
.terminal_in_body {
  background-color:rgb(44, 44, 44);
  border-top: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
  width: inherit;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}

}
.terminal_size-0{
  height: 0rem !important;
}
.terminal_size-1{
  height: 4rem;
}
.terminal_size-2{
  height: 8rem;
}
.terminal_size-3{
  height: 16rem;
}
.terminal_size-4{
  height: 32rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way

```html
<div contenteditable="true" 
  class="terminal_in_body" 
  style="height: @(sizes[terminalSize])rem;">
This is my text
</div>

<button class="terminal_btn @(terminalSize == 0?"button_hidden":"button_visiable")" 
  @onclick="Collaps" 
   title="Extend/Hide terminal" >@(terminalSize == 0?"^":"_")
</button>

@code {
  int terminalSize = 1; // 0 - collaps, 1 - 10% of screen, 2 - 20% of screen and so one
  int[] sizes = {0,4,8,16,22};
  public void Collaps()
  {
    terminalSize++;
    if(terminalSize > 4)
      terminalSize = 0;
  }
}

<style>
    .terminal_in_body {
  background-color:rgb(44, 44, 44);
  border-top: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
  width: inherit;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

[BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wPYAuDFA372TyKzY07)